# How to interpret the estimated proportions output of `prop.test` in R in >2 groups?

Tags: r, statistics, compare, output, proportions

If I have two groups:

```r
a <- c(11,14,25,34)
b <- c(23,12,42,23)
```

and I've constructed a dataframe by stacking them as such:

```r
group <- cbind(a, b)
rownames(group) <- c('icecream','pancakes','pizza','burger')
```

A `prop.test(group)` would produce the following results:

```r
    4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity
    correction

data:  group
X-squared = 9.506, df = 3, p-value = 0.02327
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.3235294 0.5384615 0.3731343 0.5964912
```

How do I interpret prop 1 through 4? For example, would prop 1 = 0.324 indicate a 32.4% overlap between a and b? Does a predict b with a 32.4% accuracy? I tried creating `group` by binding `a` and `b` in reverse order (i.e. `group <- cbind(b, a)`), and this produced different output in a `prop.test` as well.

Comment: These are just pairwise proportions. The first pair is 11 and 23. `prop 1` is 0.3235294, which is 11 / (11 + 23). Similarly `prop 2` is 14 / (14 + 12). The p value is the probability that each pair is randomly drawn from a population with the same overall proportion.

Comment: I see, thank you! What's the purpose of knowing the pairwise proportions? Can we draw any inference from a big v. small pairwise proportion?

Comment: This very much depends on what you are measuring. In your toy example, you seem to be measuring the favourite food type in two different groups, where pairwise proportions are effectively meaningless. The overall p value indicates that the two groups have significantly different tastes in food though. However, there are lots of other situations where pairwise proportions might be relevant. Context is everything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.